# Delphi XE6 Firemonkey Form

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe6

I'm trying to build an Android app on Delphi XE6 and I created a project for a FireMonkey Mobile Application. It opens a Unit1.pas but I can't seem to find the form so I can display  the objects. I tried to press F12 like I did when I worked with VCL forms.

It looks like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how I can make the Form appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was I had Embedded Designer set to false, and FireMonkey forms only work with this option set to true. If Embedded Designer is false, FireMonkey forms will only appear as plain units.

On Delphi XE6 (wich I'm currently using), to change this option it's needed to change the value of the registry key and set the Embedded Desginer value to true.

In the Registry Editor follow the path:

```
    HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Embarcadero\BDS\14.0\Form Design        

    //set the option to true
    "Embedded Designer" (REG_SZ) = "True"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a plain UNIT, not a FORM.

Delete the unit from the project and add a form.
This is a form:

[image]

Use, File / New / Multi-Device Form.

[image]

Regards.

Comment: I don't have that option! But in my project, if I choose to Add New > Firemonkey Mobile Form, shouldn't it create a form instead of a plain unit?
If I do this: [Add Form](https://gyazo.com/89623a96ca570aec20fc8fe4755ef50c), shouldn't create a form instead the play unit? Because what I get is the following: [Result](https://gyazo.com/8567cd131b4f55a8a4a8e2333e0cda3d)

Comment: As you can see here: [link](https://gyazo.com/902d375dd968501ca40e07d5bd6d80de) there TForm2 and it is of the type TForm, but the .fmx isn't created anywhere and I can't display a form also.